# How to pass hash values of ActiveRecord::Base class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have method that accept a keyword argument.

```
def foo(name:)
  p name
end
```

And I have a `ActiveRecord::Base` subclass `Person` that have a `name` attribute.

Now I'm using method by `foo(name: person.name)`.

But I want to call the method like `foo(person.slice(:name))` or `foo(person.attributes)`, because there are some other keyword arguments.

I found out that `person.slice(:name)` returns like `{"name": "Someone"}`. The key is string not a symbol, that causes error.

How can I create a hash that have symbol keys?
Maybe better way to accomplish what I want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just how ActiveRecord stores attributes. What you want is:

```
person.slice(:name).symbolize_keys
```

If you're doing this frequently you might want to patch ActiveRecord:

```
def symbolized_slice(*args)
  slice(*args).symbolize_keys
end
```

I didn't recognize that new notation for [keyword arguments](http://chriszetter.com/blog/2012/11/02/keyword-arguments-in-ruby-2-dot-0/) in Ruby 2.1. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

for recent versions of rails you can extend ActiveRecord this way:

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  primary_abstract_class

  def sym_slice(*args)
    slice(*args).symbolize_keys
  end

end
```

Usage:

```rb
Person.last.sym_slice(:name, :email) #=> { name: 'John', email: 'john@example.com' }
```